# How can I load entity form for comment?

Tags: forms, entities, 8, comments

I want to **load entity form for comment entity type**.

I can load entity form for node (entity type = node and bundle = article).

But the entity type = comment and bundle = comment.

Here is the code of loading entity:

```
  $values = [];
    $definition = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition("node");
    $bundle_key = $definition->get('entity_keys')['bundle'];
    $values['entity_type'] = "node";
    $values[$bundle_key] = "article";
    $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($definition->get('id'))
      ->create($values);
   return \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
```

=> This example works well.

But if i replace entity type with comment and bundle with comment, not work :(.

```
        $values = [];
        $definition = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition("comment");
        $bundle_key = $definition->get('entity_keys')['bundle'];
        $values['entity_type'] = "comment";
        $values[$bundle_key] = "comment";
        $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($definition->get('id'))
          ->create($values);
       return \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
```

Comment: See \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilder::getForm()

Comment: I used the **EntityFormBuilder** injected in the service 'entity.form_builder',but, my question how to load entity form comment.

Comment: Maybe this $values[$bundle_key] = "comment"; ....doesn't comments have bundles? Sorry, I haven't touched comments in D8 yet so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

it also needs the field name I think, check CommentDefaultFormatter::viewElements

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21CommentDefaultFormatter.php/class/CommentDefaultFormatter/8

It uses a lazy builder so it can be built after render caching

$output['comment_form'] = [ '#lazy_builder' => ['comment.lazy_builders:renderForm', [ $entity->getEntityTypeId(), $entity->id(), $field_name, $this->getFieldSetting('comment_type'), ]], '#create_placeholder' => TRUE, ];

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the answer to the question:

The entity type comment must be related to another entity and the other entity must have a field ( type = comment).

So here is the code for the entity form for comment related to the entity user:

```
$values = [];
$definition = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition("comment");
$bundle_key = $definition->get('entity_keys')['bundle'];
$values['entity_type'] = "user";
$values['field_name'] = "field_comments";
// comment type = comment_user(for entity type : user)
$values[$bundle_key] = "comment_user";
// user/1
$values['entity_id'] = array(
  'target_id' => 1,
);
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($definition->get('id'))
  ->create($values);


 return \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I got the solution.

For Node :

```
function d8_points_receipt_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $selected = array_filter($user_input['node_bulk_form']);
    $connection = Database::getConnection();
      if($form_state->getValue('action') == "node_publish_action") {
        foreach ($selected as $bulk_form_key) {
          $key_json_value = base64_decode($bulk_form_key);
          $key_ids = json_decode($key_json_value);
          $node_ids = array_pop($key_ids);
          $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
          $node = $node_storage->load($node_ids);
          $node_creator_id = $node->getOwnerId();
          $result = $connection->insert('d8_points_new_table')
          ->fields([
          'uid' => $node_creator_id,
          'title' => $node->get('title')->value,            
          'info_type' => 'receipt',
          'action_points' => $node->get('field_point_for_receipt_upload')->value,
          ])
            ->execute();
          }
        } 
  }
```

For Comment :

```
function d8_points_comment_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('come on');
    $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $selected = array_filter($user_input['comment_bulk_form']);
    $connection = Database::getConnection();
      if($form_state->getValue('action') == "comment_publish_action") {
        drupal_set_message('cnd ok come on');
        foreach ($selected as $bulk_form_key) {
          $key_json_value = base64_decode($bulk_form_key);
          $key_ids = json_decode($key_json_value);
          $comment_ids = array_pop($key_ids);
          $comment = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('comment')->load($comment_ids);
          $comment_creator_id = $comment->getOwnerId();
          $result = $connection->insert('d8_points_new_table')
          ->fields([
          'uid' => $comment_creator_id,
          'title' => $comment->get('subject')->value,            
          'info_type' => 'comment',
          'action_points' => $comment->get('field_point_for_comment')->value,
          ])
            ->execute();
          }
        } 
  }
```